# Slf4j multiple static binding error with Spark livy server on CDH cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, slf4j, cloudera-cdh

When I run the job in Intellij I get the desired results in logs. But when I run the same jar in our CDH 5.3 cluster where we have a Livy Server running I get the following error :-

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/2/yarn/nm/filecache/164/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hadoop/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.3-1.cdh5.3.3.p0.5/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Is there a way for me to exclude the hadoop locations slf4j jar only during spark-submit? Or any other suggestions?

We are using YARN as our Cluster Manager for Spark Job.